# How to check open or close parentheses in string before comma?

Tags: javascript

I have condition for text field that each string should have open and close parentheses before ending with comma ?

Example :

```
valid text values-  stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(0) 
Invalid          -  stack(2),flow,over(4),temp(0)
```

So , each string should have () parentheses before end with comma.How to check this condition, Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count number of () before each come with RegExp `\([^,]+\)`, it should be equal to number of comas+1

Here is working solution with test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/1/

```
function testCases(str){
    return (
    str.match(new RegExp("\\([^,]+\\)","g")).length  == str.split(",").length
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, split the string with comma, then filter it with a regexp then compare with original size.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26wtm/1/)

```
var a = 'stack(2),flow(2),over,temp ';

var arr = a.split(',');
var temp = arr;
arr = arr.filter(function(el){
    var reg = new RegExp(/\(\d+\)$/);
    el = el.trim();
    return !!reg.test(el)
});

if(arr.length !== temp.length){
    alert(temp.length - arr.length + ' wrong');
}
```

[Filter support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter)

Comment: A litle bit overly complicated in my opinion.
Wrote another solution without arrays and complicated statements.

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop to pass through each character of the string. Use a flag eg. openParentheses where you increase the count for each ( and decreases for each ) if you end up with anything other than 0 it is not valid, if you end up with anything less than 0 it is not valid and in your case if you cant have more than one parenthesis open then if your variable is greater than 1 in any iteration through the loop it is not valid. If you need to look for the coma too, just when you find a ) check for [i+1] to see if it is a comma. Watch out if it is the end of the string so you don't get an out of bounds error. Either make a special case (if) or add some dummy character to the end which is not ).